# Error On Database Import To Azure Instaance

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm getting the following error while importing database to an azure instance which is actually a .bacpac backup of existing database in the same instance.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Could not import package.
Error Deploy72002: DeploymentContributor 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.Extensions.CreateDatabaseWithCustomEditionDeploymentModifier' threw exception. Message is: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlFragment Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.DeploymentScriptDomStep.get_Script()'.'
 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

DeploymentContributor 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.Extensions.CreateDatabaseWithCustomEditionDeploymentModifier' threw exception. Message is: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlFragment Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.DeploymentScriptDomStep.get_Script()'.' (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions)

---

Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlFragment Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.DeploymentScriptDomStep.get_Script()'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions)

---

Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlFragment Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment.DeploymentScriptDomStep.get_Script()'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Services.ImportExport.DacFxExtensions)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Hi @Jesalcv, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Jesalcv; did you find a solution?  Could one solution be to upgrade to a newer SQL Server (as an evaluation version)?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to download the latest Data-tier Framework from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56048). Download the latest version of SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).